# Lag with 4K and secondary VGA with 1080 ti

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have a EVGA 1080 ti in a 16x slot.  Motherboard is Asus ROG running AMD Threadripper, 32GB ram, SSD, Samsung 4K via HDMI, cheap Dell 19" on DVI, Windows 10 64.  Pretty simple configuration.

If I open a video (Netflix/Amazon) on the 4K and start a windowed game I start getting lag real quick.  If I move the video to the secondary 19" monitor, it's hit or miss.  Netflix gets really bad with noticeable lag between video and audio sometimes.  Combined video modes are well under the max resolution combinations for 1080ti's

Recently updated to latest driver, no real change.

I'm looking for tips and suggestions to solving this issue.  Searches have been less than fruitful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking your drivers? NVIDIA drivers tend to mess up (if it's a 1080ti from NVIDIA). I'd try getting a drivers updater (from the 1080ti manufacturers site,) and running it and let it reinstall all display drivers (NOTE: Screen will flash during driver removal/installation. Don't panic.). If that don't work, make sure your RAM is fully working. Sometimes a RAM stick can act like it's working but it's really not. If it's a custom built, try checking the RAM, the CPU, and the 1080ti and make sure everything is in good and not loose.

Comment: Grizzly, thanks for the quick response.  Yes, downloaded latest from EVGA.  I have tried both theirs and nvidia's in the past, similar issue.  What's weird is that the problem isn't consistent.

Comment: Hmm... Is there any RAM/CPU issues? Try looking at the "Performance" tab in Task Manager and tell me if it gets high. What web browser do you use?

Comment: Grizzly, the CPU/RAM/GPU usage remains low.  I stumbled across a random article late last night that describe a frequency race condition.  The 4K monitor is at 60hz, the 19" is running at 75hz.  I changed that 75hz to 60hz and see if that helps.

Comment: any lucko, bucko?

Comment: No lag since syncing the refresh rate on both monitors.  If it has issues I will update, otherwise I might write this off as closed.

Comment: Alright, good luck!